# Is it possible to create a Uri without a scheme/protocol?

Tags: asp.net, uri

I've got a static environment (in the code below refered to as '*staticsite.com*') where I store images for my ASP.NET web application and I want to dynamically build up a URI without specifying the scheme.

The following code doesn't work, because it automatically assigns the `file://` scheme to the Uri.

```
Dim baseUri As New Uri("//staticsite.com")
Dim imageUri As New Uri(baseUri, imgUrl.ToString())
```

After this, baseUri is `file://staticsite.com`. imageUri becomes `file://staticsite.com/someImage.jpg`

Is it possible to create a new Uri instance without a scheme/protocol? In the end, I want to have a Uri starting with `//staticsite.com` and correctly formatted / appended with the `imgUrl`.

By the way, the reason I'm using Uri is because I don't know if the imgUrl begins with "/" or not and using Uri allegedly was the best option.